# client websocket connect through proxy

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio, http-proxy

I'm using the [websockets](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets) module, but it doesn't support connecting though my corporate proxy for a client connection:

```
>>> import asyncio, websockets
>>> async def connect(uri):
...     async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
...         pass
...
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect('ws://myhost.com/path/'))
    ....
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('myhost.com', 80)
```

However if use curl with my `http_proxy` env var set, it works:

```
$ curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: MTIzNDEyMzQxMjM0MTIzNA==" http://myhost.com/path/
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: nginx/1.13.6
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 14:51:00 GMT
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s+CT5bkW5F3N2/5JUXrCPtLHn68=
Connection: Upgrade
```

What are my best options? Some other module for making client-websocket connects?

Comment: `websockets` don't support client connection through proxy. https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/limitations.html

So use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client

Comment: @Ahsan: You're a couple of years late, see my answer to my own question below.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your answer but didn't find anywhere why you left `websockets`  and moved to `websocket-client`.  Actually I was in situation to choose one between these two. So proxy is limitation for `websockets`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pip install` [websocket-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client). Then place your `http*_proxy` variables in `os.environ` as you normally do. Code like so:

```
ws = websocket.create_connection('ws://example.com/path')
ws.send(out_data)
in_data = ws.recv()
```

If you don't know exactly what protocols your proxy uses, set up both `http*_proxy` variables like this example:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://jonasb:password@proxyserver:8000
$ export https_proxy=https://jonasb:password@proxyserver:8000
```

(assuming your username is jonasb, and port is 8000).

Comment: Bystrom, Do i need to use `https_proxy` or `http?_proxy`? I'm having same proxy for http, https and ftp. Can you please help?

Comment: I'm getting this error : `websocket._exceptions.WebSocketProxyException: failed CONNECT via proxy status: 503`. Can you help with this? Do i need to ask in new question?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/124897/503-service-unavailable-what-really-it-means) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26528/error-503-service-unavailable-when-using-apt-get-update-behind-proxy) perhaps? I remember getting 503 a long time ago, but unfortunately cannot recall the cause. Check your hostname and port. Drop username+password. Ask your admin. Poke around.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If possible to look at my question at which i explained in detail. This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586749/websocket-exceptions-websocketproxyexception-failed-connect-via-proxy-status)

Comment: @JonasByström what about socks/tor based proxies ?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a package to do just that via `websockets` package.

Check it out: https://github.com/racinette/websockets_proxy